# Set the name of the document when it is created

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to edit this "Generate from Template" script. What the script does is based on a template it inputs information from a Spreadsheet to a Document. I like how it works except that it just names the document a copy of the template then the row number. This isn't very efficient for what i am trying to use this for. My question is how would i be able to do one of these options:

A: Have the name be based on a certain Cell in the row. For example, there is a column named Claim # and Department. I would like both of those to make up the title for each document. The document would be: " {department name} {claim #} " based on the information in that column in that row that was exported.

B: Have a box to put in when generating the document that asks what i want the file to be named.

Thank you for your help!

PS: If it is needed the columns that i would use for the name of the document are: column E then Column D.

This is the code: (I did not make this, i found it in the gallery.)

```
function generateDocument(e) {
  var template = DocsList.getFileById(e.parameter.Templates);
  var row = e.parameter.row
  var myDocID = template.makeCopy(template.getName()+" - "+ row).getId();
  var myDoc = DocumentApp.openById(myDocID);
  var copyBody = myDoc.getActiveSection();
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Browser.msgBox(row);
  var myRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(row+":"+row);
  for (var i=1;i<Sheet.getLastColumn()+1;i++){
    var myCell = myRow.getCell(1, i);
    copyBody.replaceText("{"+myCell.getA1Notation().replace(row,"")+"}", myCell.getValue());
  }
  myDoc.saveAndClose();
  //var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 
  //MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {cc: carbonCopy, name: senderName, htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf}); 

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app; 
}

function getTemplates() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Generate from template');
  // Create a grid with 3 text boxes and corresponding labels
  var grid = app.createGrid(3, 2);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Template name:'));

  var list = app.createListBox();
  list.setName('Templates');
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, list);
  var docs = DocsList.getFolder("Templates").getFilesByType("document");
  for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
    list.addItem(docs[i].getName(),docs[i].getId());
  }
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Row:'));
  var row = app.createTextBox().setName('row');
  row.setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getRow());
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, row);
  // Create a vertical panel..
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  // ...and add the grid to the panel
  panel.add(grid);

  // Create a button and click handler; pass in the grid object as a callback element and the handler as a click handler
  // Identify the function b as the server click handler

  var button = app.createButton('Submit');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('generateDocument');
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  // Add the button to the panel and the panel to the application, then display the application app in the Spreadsheet doc
  panel.add(button);
  app.add(panel);
  doc.show(app);
}

function onOpen() {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Generate from template", functionName: "getTemplates"}];  
  ss.addMenu("Template Generator", menuEntries);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The makeCopy method includes the possibility to give a name to the copy, the autocomplete shows it clearly

[image]
So in your code you could do it like this :

```
function generateDocument(e) {
  var template = DocsList.getFileById(e.parameter.Templates);
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();// I moved this line a bit to have Sheet available 
  var row = e.parameter.row
  var myDocID = template.makeCopy(Sheet.getRange('E'+row).getValue()+'-'+Sheet.getRange('D'+row).getValue()).getId();// this is a basic implementation to compose the name with content of column D and E separated by a hyphen... customize it the way you want.
  ...
```